# Designing a boot loader for simple Z80 system via UART, Where To Load the Program

Tags: c, assembly, embedded, bootloader, z80

I've started writing a boot loader for my z80 system.
So far the program can accept hex via serial and load it to a location in the memory.

The problem I have though is the boot loader is at the start of memory and uses the interrupts, 
How can I load a new program with out overwriting the boot loader?

(Also a loaded program might want to use the interrupts as well)

Comment: You need to decide what you can load.  Can you disallow loads to low mem, define a "start of load region", and the loaded program has to initialize the interrupt vectors when it starts?  Or your loader can use interrupts and relocate any load data addressed to low mem to a special area.  Prior to program start, disable ints and copy the special area to low mem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best and most widely used approach is to split your app into a stable boot loader that is never updated, and the application that you can replace from time to time.

AFAIK, in Z80 there are just interrupt vectors and there no support for replacing them in the CPU itself. You need to have something in your hardware that will replace your memory blocks.

Othewise you need to have feature that bootloaders is not using anything in the app part during the download and block any interrupts that can call anything in the app.

Comment: Yeh i think I got a solution, to have the main boot loader code at the end of memory. Use the interrupts and store the code in memory temporarily, then want the entire program is received, disable interrupts and move the temporarily stored code to 0000H and reset the PC.

I don't think it's the most efficient method, but at least it's a start.

Comment: My Z80 CP/M system from 1983 switches the first 4KB block between the boot EPROM and the dynamic RAM covering the complete 64KB address space.  IIRC it boots from EPROM and switches to RAM on the first instruction access outside of the 4KB.

Comment: yeh but what about interrupts that get pointed to 0038H and 0066H (NMI) ?

A program has no access to here if it's ROM

Answer (score 2):

W.r.t. locations, you may place the bootloader at the top of the address space and load a program at the beginning of the address space.

You can also include the location and size of the program in the protocol so the bootloader would be able to check whether the pair of values is compatible with the bootloader location and size (IOW, whether or not the program would overwrite the bootloader if loaded).

Another option is to include relocation information in the program and a simple relocator in the bootloader. That way you'd be able to load the program at any location if there's enough free memory. This is what many OSes do when they load programs.

As for the interrupts, I don't see a problem. Who or what is there not to allow the program to use interrupts? Or do you want the bootloader to say resident and either continue to do something in the background or be able to return to it from the program? If you don't need any of these, just let the program use the interrupts (you probably don't even need to do anything to allow that).

If, OTOH, you do want the bootloader to remain functional you can introduce an extra layer of indirection by maintaining an additional interrupt vector table. The primary ISRs would extract the secondary ISRs from this interrupt vector table and jump there. Your bootloader and program would then need to do this in order to add a new or override an existing ISR:

1. disable interrupts
2. get the old ISR address from the additional interrupt vector table
3. put the new ISR address into the table
4. enable interrupts

Removing an ISR is obvious and similar to the above.

The new ISR can then:

1. before doing its work call the old ISR (the address is preserved at step 2 above)
2. after doing its work call the old ISR
3. just do its work without calling the old ISR

You need to require that the programs and bootloader use this table and restore it when they no longer need to have their own ISRs in it.

I don't know what issues you may need to solve if you chain ISRs by executing the old ones before/after the new ones. But in some systems that's a possible design. Many x86 PC programs and drivers did that in MSDOS.

Comment: Yeh thanks for the first tip, I'll definitely place check so the boot loader can spew back if the program is too large which may occur as it's only 16kB.

I was thinking if I wanted to return to the bootloader, i could place a return call at the end of the program, and the bootloader could then rewrite to the appropriate locations its interrupt code for those locations (going to just be a disable interrupts and a jump)